# Can one create a private registry in Win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to develop something and it needs an hierarchical database. Is there any way in Win32 to create one's own personal registry, and use registry functions to populate and manage it?

Comment: There is Sandboxie. I wonder how it does private registries? http://vallejo.cc/?p=48#more-48

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use the real registry.
Use `HKCU\Software\Your Company\Your Product`.

Comment: Okay, how much of that is affected by UAC?

Comment: @boost: UAC prevents you from writing to machine-wide keys and files, just like a non-administrative user.  HKCU is fine.  If your (normal) program is affected by UAC, you're (probably) doing something wrong.

Comment: That's a useful comment. You should add that to the answer.